# Shift Javascript framework - What pattern is this? MVP, MVC or something else

Tags: design, design-patterns, javascript

I have created a very tiny framework to be able to get away from all the clutter while developing. The point of the framework is not to replace any library of choice but simply segregate the code to it's correct logic.

You can see the source on github along with a few code examples: https://github.com/erik-landvall/shift

While I try to describe the pattern I'm using I'm starting to wonder how this should be defined. And that's my question for you. What would you say the following chart symbolizes?

[image: Flowchart of the shift framework]

I like to think of it as an MVP pattern, but would like to hear your opinion.

Also, if you feel that the flowchart poorly resampling the code, give me a comment about it and I will attempt to fix it.

Comment: Based on your examples it's not MVC that's for sure, the views have too much logic and the controllers are more of presenters indeed. I think MVP is probably the right choice.

Comment: My question also involves if this could be considered a different pattern then mvc or mvp
I re-write the title and explain a bit better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVP. In classic MVC, both the view and controller can access the model. In your case you have a coordinating <strike>object</strike> logical layer (the Presenter in your case, see diagram below) with knowledge of both the model and view, keeping those two isolated.

An additional comment to this. [Fowler retired MVP from his catalog of patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html) and split it into two: [Supervising Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) and [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). I haven't looked into your code, but it's worth reading about them.

[image: mvp]

Comment: thanks for your answer and the links, will look them over...